# Why my UIRefreshControl overlaps and blocks the UICollectionViewCell content

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uirefreshcontrol

I embedded a UICollectionView in a UIViewController and tried to add a UIRefreshControl into the UICollectionView with these code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    ......

    //  Create the UIRefreshControl.
    let pullDownLogo = UIRefreshControl()
    pullDownLogo.clipsToBounds = true

    //  Create a UIImageView.
    let pullDownImgView = UIImageView(frame: pullDownLogo.bounds)
    pullDownImgView.image = UIImage(named: "fa-heart")
    pullDownImgView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    pullDownImgView.clipsToBounds = true

    //  Add the UIImageView into UIRefreshControl.
    pullDownLogo.addSubview(pullDownImgView)
    WatchListCollectionView.addSubview(pullDownLogo)

    ......

}
```

**When I pulled down the collection view and not reached the bottom, the image did show.

The problem is: the image overlapped and blocked the collectionView cell.

What I want is the image in the refresh controller be blocked by the cell content.**

The problem is shown in this snapshot:

[image: error]

Comment: This is off topic and I apologize but are you somehow using font awesome in swift (`fa-heart`)? On another note I also had this issue using the default RefreshControl setup, i improved the look by just removing the message and only showing the spinning indicator. You are using a custom image so the problem is more apparent

Comment: @AtheistP3ace I just extract an icon from font awesome as an png imported into my project. I don't want it refresh actually, I just want it shows a logo when I pull the collection view down.

Comment: did you ever sort this problem? I'm running into it myself.

Comment: @Kyle No, I haven't.